# UIScrollView scrollToTop not working on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in IOS, and i have UIView contains UIScrollView and i want it to scroll to top when tapping the status bar but i have some UITextField and i used gesture to dismiss the keyboard when tapping outside, how can i scroll my scrollView when tapping on status bar ? this is the method i am using to dismiss the keyboard

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
    {
        if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

and this the delegate method for scrollToTop

```
-(BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
        return YES ;
    }
```

could any one help me?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure, this scroll view -is the only- scroll view on the screen that returns scrollTopTop = YES.

Set all the other to scrollTopTop = NO.

Comment: i did it but not working, i think the statusbar tap not detected

Answer (score 0):

Try using `contentOffset` property of scrollView

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(someXvalue,someYvalue);  // replace with your values e.g (0,-200)
```